# How does cargo manage dependency versions?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I was reading [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#ensuring-reproducible-builds-with-the-cargolock-file) at the guessing game tutorial inside the rust book

---

## Ensuring Reproducible Builds with the Cargo.lock File

Cargo has a mechanism that ensures you can rebuild the same artifact every time you or anyone else builds your code: Cargo will use only the versions of the dependencies you specified until you indicate otherwise. For example, say that next week version 0.8.4 of the rand crate comes out, and that version contains an important bug fix, but it also contains a regression that will break your code. To handle this, Rust creates the Cargo.lock file the first time you run cargo build, so we now have this in the guessing_game directory.

When you build a project for the first time, Cargo figures out all the versions of the dependencies that fit the criteria and then writes them to the Cargo.lock file. When you build your project in the future, Cargo will see that the Cargo.lock file exists and use the versions specified there rather than doing all the work of figuring out versions again. This lets you have a reproducible build automatically. In other words, your project will remain at 0.8.3 until you explicitly upgrade, thanks to the Cargo.lock file.

---

but didn't quite understand how cargo garantees that we have/need the correct version of a dependency. For instance, if we put in the [dependecies] rand="0.8.3" it will not exactly download the crate at this version, but the crate the match the needs of our program but it's compatible with this version(?)

Please clarify this logic!

Comment: Are you talking _with_ or _without_ Cargo.lock?

Comment: I'd like to clarify one thing: cargo does not look at your Rust source when selecting crate versions, only at the constraints in the dependency sections of all involved `Cargo.toml`s. The whole behavior is complex enough that there's several relevant book chapters: [1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/cargo-toml-vs-cargo-lock.html) [2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) [3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying a crate in `Cargo.toml`, you can give an exact version (e.g. `=0.8.3`) or more general indications (e.g. `0.8.*`).

If you specify `rand = "=0.8.3"` in `Cargo.toml`, then cargo will take version 0.8.3 (note the extra `=` inside the version requirement). But if you specify `rand = "*"`, then the first time you build your crate it will take the latest version and write this version to `Cargo.lock`. That way if you rebuild your crate later cargo will reuse the same version even if a new version has been published on crates.io in the meantime.

Note btw that specifying `rand = "0.8.3"` does *not* mean "exactly version 0.8.3", but instead means "any version >=0.8.3 and <0.9": [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-cratesio).